# Why does order of instantiation seem to matter for input and output streams in Java?

Tags: java, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I have the following code that works (please assume that hostname and port are initialized to their proper values, and that Message is a serializable class):

```
//Example 1 - everything works as expected
Message message = new Message();
try(Socket serverSocket = new Socket(hostname, port))
{
    ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(serverSocket.getOutputStream());                  
    outStream.writeObject(message);
    outStream.flush();

    ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(serverSocket.getInputStream());
    Object response = inStream.readObject();
}
```

When I move the instantiation of the `ObjectInputStream` to occur immediately after the `ObjectOutputStream` instantiation, execution of my application hangs indefinitely:

```
//Example 2 - client locks up
Message message = new Message();
try(Socket serverSocket = new Socket(hostname, port))
{
    ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(serverSocket.getOutputStream());                  
    ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(serverSocket.getInputStream());

    outStream.writeObject(message);
    outStream.flush();

    Object response = inStream.readObject();
}
```

I'm looking for a good explanation as to why the second example locks up consistently, and the first example seems to work without a hitch. Strangely, if I use a debugger (Eclipse debugger) on the client and server with this second example, I'm seeing the message make it through to the server, so the `writeObject()` call is being executed. However, in the client, the debugger gets stuck on the constructor for the `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: I wonder whether you aren't experiencing a race internal to the `Socket`. Try placing a Thread.sleep(100) between the instantiations of the streams and see if it works. If so, then you will at least know that it is a race.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: @pens-fan-69 Adding sleeps to network code is just cargo-cult programming. It doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Can you step into the constructor to see what line it hangs?

Comment: @pens-fan-69 Can you read the two correct answers that have already been posted? And stop guessing?

Comment: @EJP I suggested it simply to find out more info, not as a solution.

Comment: @pens-fan-69 And I suggested you read the two correct answers, which are a solution, and you haven't done it. You're just wasting time and space.

Comment: @EJP I was also on a mobile device that hadn't updated with the solutions. Not trying to step on anybody's toes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we go and have a read of the API docs for the `ObjectInputStream` [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream%28java.io.InputStream%29)

The important part:

> This constructor will block until the corresponding ObjectOutputStream
>   has written and flushed the header.

Answer (score 1):

Constructing an `ObjectOutputStream` writes a header to the stream. Constructing an `ObjectInputStream` reads it. If both ends construct the `ObjectInputStream` first, you will therefore get a deadlock.

Solution: construct the `ObjectOutputStream` first, at both ends, to make sure it can't happen.